# Large loft area cooling

Tags: air-conditioning

I believe the dimensions of the room are about  36' x 12'.  It is the upstairs room, and has a loft looking out to the front room.  In the summer it is almost impossible to cool down, the air vents are in the floor.  Does anyone have any recommendations on cooling this room off?  I do own the condo, and there is a small window at one end of the room.  We have two ceiling fans in the room, but they don't seem to do much to help.

Comment: What sort of climate are you in, and is there insulation above the ceiling of this loft space?

Answer (score -1):

You need to raise the returns to near the ceiling and possibly add more supplies and returns. A picture of the return and supply registers would help determine just how hard it will be to raise the  returns. Also, can this room be isolated from the lower level or is just an open stairway. In some of the condos near where I live it is not possible to maintain a comfortable temperature in these upper rooms without a 2nd dedicated unit due to the homes construction.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t intend to downvote, and it’s not letting me reverse it.